# Only display 20 rows of data from a csv file with d3.js

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

What I'm trying to figure out is a way to create a script that would take the first 20 rows of data from a CSV file, after loading the full CSV file that has over 3000 entries, and just display 20 at a time in a bar graph.  That way I could have two buttons that would take me back and forth between 20 rows of data each time, instead of all 3000 bars displaying at once, making the graph not even readable.

Short of cutting up the CSV file into groups of 20, and loading the next CSV file each time you click "next", I'm not sure how to even go about doing this.

Comment: 7rystan If you want, copy the answer, because since the question was put on hold as unclear I'll delete the answer soon.

Comment: Is it alright if I update the post to be more clear so that it won't be removed?  The answer was exactly what I needed.

Comment: It was put on hold as *unclear*. Thus, you certainly can edit the question to make it more clear (actually, that is the purpose of putting on hold: giving OP a chance to clarify his/her question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the type of the dataviz (a bar chart, for instance), 3000 items is definitely too much. However, it's normally not that much regarding the file size.

That being said, instead of cutting it up in several files with 20 rows, load **all** the items at once, in a single CSV, and display only 20 each time (which is what your question's title say).

To cut the data array, use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
var slicedData = data.slice(begin, end);
```

Here is a basic demo:

```js
var body = d3.select("body");
body.append("p").html("ID -- VALUE<br>");
var index = 0

d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ffishman/a8cd485c44bee39b68c7a5c7fad14f17/raw/fad1cd9a10f313c06ec65bd8ab289c818536681c/flare.csv", function(data) {
  d3.select("#bt2").on("click", () => {
    var newData = data.slice(index, index + 20);
    index += 20;
    update(newData);
  })

  d3.select("#bt1").on("click", () => {
    index -= 20;
    var newData = data.slice(index - 20, index);
    update(newData)
  })

  function update(newData) {
    var par = body.selectAll(".par")
      .data(newData, d => d.id);

    par.exit().remove();

    par.enter()
      .append("p")
      .attr("class", "par")
      .merge(par)
      .html(d => d.id + " -- " + d.value)
  }
})
```

```css
p {
    margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<button id="bt1">Previous 20</button>
<button id="bt2">Next 20</button>
```